# Safe URI building

Tags: java, http

I'm writing a class in Java which access the url `http://hostA/webProjectB/ServletC` with some parameters. Since it is a get http call I can append the parameters to the URL ..

```
http://hostA/webProjectB/ServletC?parameter1=California&parameter2=yes
```

This returns a response in xml format `<root><parameter3>123</parameter3></root>`

Basically I'm interested in extracting the value of parameter3 in my http response which I know how to do.

My question is the WebUrl upto the servlet I'm storing in an external configuration which I retrieve as a String and can I simply append the get call parameters 1 and 2 to this string I retrieve ? Will this create any possible issues if I built the get URL as a string ?

Comment: Can you explain with code starting from "My question is" and what issues you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you are encoding the parameters you are defining correctly, i.e. using `URLEncoder.encode(string,charset)`.

You might be better served with one of the URI templating libraries, i.e. [Handy URI Templates](https://github.com/damnhandy/Handy-URI-Templates) or the [JAX-RS UriBuilder](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html)

Otherwise, as long as you are escaping characters correctly (i.e.  `URLEncoder.encode(string,charset)` for both the param name and value) you should be fine